# Dagger 2 application using library that uses dagger 1

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

I am finding myself in situation where  I am transitioning application from using Dagger 1 to Dagger 2. However this application uses a library that is using Dagger 1 and during my application startup I get following exception

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldagger/ObjectGraph; 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dagger.ObjectGraph" on path: DexPathList[
```

I do have progard file but that keeps everything Dagger prefix. So question is, do I need to convert this library to dagger2 or those two things should co-exists?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have an application with both Dagger1 and Dagger2. You will however need to add both as dependencies in gradle.